# One activity, onboarding + multiple backStacks fragments with bottom navigation

Tags: android-fragments, androidx, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation

Just visited the [google repo](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample) on the last alpha realease of navigation library, version 2.4.0-alpha02. I have a big doubt on what will be the right approach to show a onBoarding graph and then load the navgraph of multiple stacks, all that in just one activity.

If I understand correctly, the `FragmentContainerView`, in the last update, it needs a navGraph with the `<include>`of the sections we want to have inside our app, and a startDestination of one of that includes.

The doubt on navigation:

What would be the right implementation? I mean, I looked at the docs and the part of conditional navigation, but this part does not seems to fit inside.

What I tried:

1. I inflate inside the FragmentContainerView the navGraph of the onboarding, then after the onboarding its done, I inflate inside the same FragmentContainer another navgraph, the one for the multiple backStack, this aproach seems to have a visual impact, because the view when the FragmentContainerView gets his navGraph inflated inside, the view goes white...
2. I used the fragmentManager of activity as the NavHost, to load first the onBoarding graph and then the FragmentContainerView with his navGraph, this option improve the visual problem mentioned in 1. but the multiple backstack stopped working, my guess is that FragmentContainerView, needs to be the navHost.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I just implemented multi back stacks and I am having the same issue as you. If I pop the on boarding nav from the backstack so the user cant navigate back to it from the home screen it breaks the multiple back stack support.

Comment: @AndroidDev123 I took the 1º Step!

Answer (score 0):

Speaking to Ian Lake who designed the navigation component he stated that We should never use the splash screen or onboarding screen as our start destination. Instead you should use conditional navigation to direct the user to the splash screen or onboarding screen if required. He then linked me the following article

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/navigation-conditional-navigation-e82d7e4905f0

Comment: Your answear does not have anything to do with this question, this is not navigating to a new destination, but it's loading a navgraph or other on a condition within the FragmentContainerView!. And now going back to your afirmation, if you do that then you have to stick the onBoarding navGraph inside your first NavGraph which in my opinion is a mess!